# With collapse only reveal next/one element

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following templates in Flask (but I don't think that's a flask problem:

## Contact.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-target="#score" data-toggle="collapse" data-placement="right">Score</button>
<div id="score" class="collapse">
    <span class='dot green'></span> 1
</div>
```

## Compare.html

```
<!-- I only added the key elements there are some other "formatting" parts.-->
{% include "contact.html" %}
{% include "contact.html" %}
```

As you see in Contact.html I use a collpase. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

My problem is that I compare two contacts and therefore they both have that `div` with id `score`.
If I now click on the first Button to reveal the score of the first contact then obviously both scores are revealed. But I only want to reveal the score of the contact I clicked.

My idea is instead of `data-target="#score"` to say something like: `Take the next #score element` but I don't know how I can do that.

Comment: what about using BS4 Accordion (and of course you will have to change their ids like score1 and score2 because id's cannot be same in a dom tree.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out how to it. Basically it's easy in my case.

Because each contact has an unique id, I can use this to build the id like this:

```
<!-- Generate ID -->
{% set score_id = "score" + contact.idx|string  %}

<!-- Use the ID in the collapse-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-target="#{{score_id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-placement="right">Score</button>
<div id="{{score_id}}" class="collapse">
    <span class='dot {{color}}'></span> {{ contact_score }}
</div>
```

Then only one will expanded if clicked on the Button. Therefore thanks [@Anees Ijaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934118/with-collapse-only-reveal-next-one-element#comment105990317_59934118) for the comment. The comment pushed me in the right direction.